# Beeping while KeyDown is triggered

Tags: c++, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I have a `TListView` (it is focused all the time) and an `OnKeyDown` event handler  on my Form (its `KeyPreview` property is true).

`playlist` is my `TListView` component (`Style = vsReport`).

```
void __fastcall Tmform::mformKeyDown(TObject *Sender, WORD &Key, TShiftState Shift)
{
  if(Shift.Contains(ssCtrl))            // hotkeys with CTRL
  {
     switch(Key)
     {
        case vkF: findDoublesbtnClick(mform);  break;        // [FIND TWINS]
        case vkD: dbsClick(mform);             break;        // [DELETE BAD SONGS]
        case vkA: playlist->SelectAll();       break;        // [CTRL + A]
        case vkS: settingsClick(mform);        break;        // [SETTINGS]
     }
  }
  else                                  // just keys
  {
     switch(Key)
     {
        case vkReturn:  if(playlist->SelCount) pl.refreshSong();        break;   // [ENTER]
        case vkDelete:   af.deleteFiles();      break;        // [DELETE]
        case vkSpace:
        case vkNumpad3:  pl.playPauseResume();  break;
        case vkSubtract: prevbtnClick(mform);   break;        // [PREVIOUS]
        case vkAdd:      nextbtnClick(mform);   break;        // [NEXT]
        case vkC:        counterClick(mform);   break;        // [LISTENINGS WIN]
     }
}
```

Why does it beep when I press any key (with the `TListView` focused)?

Comment: Could someone explain, why my question is downvoted?

Comment: Because you don't provide proper details. For all we know, the issue could be the code in your `FormKeyDown` event handler. Which we cannot see. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try to fix my mistake.

Comment: I think it is because the list handles the `keydown` event (I guess default method is to play a beep), so it not handled by the form. so I guess you need to catch keydown also in the listView and handle it by roll it over to the form `keydown` method.

Comment: It's been a while, but I seem to recall that you can suppress the beep by setting the Key value to zero in the handler.

Comment: No, there is no changing `Key` value in my code. I use it only in switches.

Comment: I know, but try setting its value to zero after acting on it - it's a reference.

Comment: No, unfortunately it still beeps when I set value to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found out, **why** it beeps. It seems to be standard behavior of TListView component. When one item in TListView is selected (and TListView has focus), any character input triggers "select the typed item" method, that trying to find and select item by our input.

That was the answer I was interested about. To make work hot keys (including one-key) I used next code:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::ListViewKeyPress(TObject *Sender, System::WideChar &Key)
{  Key = 0; }     // here TListView calls "find" method. I reset Key value,
                  // thus I have only vkCode for FormKeyDown which triggers
                  // after FormKeyPress
void __fastcall TForm1::FormKeyDown(TObject *Sender, WORD &Key, TShiftState Shift)
{
    if (Shift.Contains(ssAlt) && Key == vkF)                // use any key or shortcut
    {  Form1->Color = RGB(random(255), 0, 0);  return; }    // you wish
    if (Key == vkF)
       Form1->Color = RGB(0, random(255), 0);
    if (Key == vkSpace)
       Form1->Color = RGB(0, 0, random(255));
}
```

It works with all existing PC keyboard layouts. But with 'alt' and 'win' keys still beeps, because any key
with 'alt' or 'win' does not triger the ListViewKeyPress event.

Thank for your help!

Comment: Setting the `Key` parameter to 0 in the `OnKey...` events is the correct and documented way to discard key strokes before they reach the ListView. Try using `OnKeyPress` instead of `OnKeyDown`

Comment: I couldn't make it to work with `Key = 0`. And how to process it in `OnKeyPress` if input language can be different, therefore different chars?  P.S. To hear beep I select any item and wait about 1 sec. Beep doesn't appear if press faster.

Comment: A beep happens when you press a key that does not match the first letter of a list item. When I set `Key` to 0 in `OnKeyDown`, it suppresses *most* of the beeps. The beeps that make it through only happen after the ListView selection changes. The first press beeps, subsequent beeps are suppressed until the selection changes again. But setting `Key` to 0 in `OnKeyPress` suppresses *all* of the beeps.

Comment: With `OnKeyPress` it works fine, that's result I desired. How then to make it works with many languages?

Comment: The code you showed is not using any chars that are language-dependent. But, if necessary, you can set/clear a flag in `OnKeyDown` when you want to  suppress/allow a given char, clear the flag in `OnKeyUp`, and set `Key` to 0 in `OnKeyPress` if the flag is set.

Comment: Yes, because that would be better solution. But with `OnKeyPress` I`ll can get such chars: `[s, ы, i]`. I guess there is a couple chars for other languages. Thank you so much for help!